# Where can I find Anna, the Baron's wife?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm stuck during the second part of the quest "Family Matters". I've found the Baron's daughter, but I can't find any more leads to find his wife.

The quest descriptions isn't really helpful in this case, it just says "Investigate all remaining leads in Velen and find the Baron's wife". Well, Velen is pretty big, and I don't know where to start. I did try to find more clues at the place where she was attacked and abducted, but there doesn't seem to be anything more there.

Where can I find the next clue about what happened there?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Complete the quest: *"Ladies of the Wood"*.

I finally found the Baron's wife, it turns out the part about investigating all remaining leads refers to the leads about Ciri. There are two quest series about Ciri in Velen, and at this point you have to follow the other quest series to complete the "Family Matters" quest,  and "Ladies of the Wood".

Comment: I recall investigatin a witch that turned out to be a sorceress of the lodge who was also an ally of geralt, i dont recall her name, but it was the third one besides yen and triss. We did an elven mage quest and she gave me a book which left me on that same quest status about investigating the leads. I only had to read the book to move on to the next step and see the quest (find the trail of treats)

Comment: @Ryan I think you are talking about [Keira Metz](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Keira_Metz). Yes, the "Ladies of the Wood" quest branches off of her questline.